# Java - Getting Numbers in an Array

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that takes input from a user, such as "1 5 3 6 3 5 0" all in one line. I would like to take this input and store each number in an array. So for example, my array would have values 1, 5, 3, 6, 3, 5, 0.

I do not even know where to start with this. I know to create a scanner. I thought that maybe I could do nextLine(); and then just separate it by spaces and put the values into an array.. However, nextLine() only takes strings.

Comment: And strings can be `split()`, if need be. Or you can take a number at a time. Try putting up what code you already have.

Comment: [Integer.parseInt(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Comment: Whatever is put as command line argument is a *String* though it looks as a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, as long as the numbers are entered with spaces between them, this will populate an array of ints:

```
    System.out.println("Enter something > ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //read in string entered by user
    String inputString = input.nextLine();

    //split the string into an array of strings, using [space]
    String[] split = inputString.split(" ");

    //create a new int array, and populate it with the contents of the split string
    int intarray[] = new int[split.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        intarray[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.split()` or `.chatAt(position)` separate each element from the entire String.

```
String a = example.charAt(0);
```

this would copy the first character, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "1 5 3 6 3 5 0";
String[] inputs = input.split(" ");
ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (String s : inputs) {
     values.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
}
System.out.println(values);
```

This prints `[1, 5, 3, 6, 3, 5, 0]`.

Answer (score 0):

u may try nextInt():

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] nums = new int[5];
out.printf("Enter %d numbers, space separated: ", nums.length);
for(int i = 0; nums.length > i; i ++) {
    nums[i] = scn.nextInt();
}
out.println("\nYour values are:");
for(int i : nums) {
    out.printf("%-8d", i);// u may use //out.printf("%d\t", i);
}
```